# Detect minimum speed of a dynamic node in 3d space

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

I have a 3d dynamic node with speed & acceleration vectors. It has maximum speed (magnitude) and minimum speed such as if it exceeds maximum or goes below minimum, it stops accelerating and the speed is set to the respective maximum or minimum.

I have no problem detecting the maximum, I just have to check if the magnitude of speed vector is superior to the maximum.

But I am struggling for the minimum detection, magnitudes being in the positive field it seems to me more tricky.
For example I want a minimum speed near 0, or 0, the object is decelerating, at one point it will pass through 0 and start accelerating following acceleration vector.

For example speed magnitude could be as such through frames:
5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6 .. etc

There is no way to know if it did pass through zero, it could have well passed over zero between 2 and 1 and accelerate after, or between any other number.

Each frame I have these data: last speed vector, actual speed vector, acceleration vector.

How can I detect that next frame I'll cross my minimum value (zero in that example) ?

Comment: Wha's the problem with `if (acceleration < 0 && magnitude < abs(acceleration)) do stuff`?

Comment: what is 'acceleration' ? It can either be a 3d vector or its magnitude (positive).

Comment: it's the magnitude.

Comment: Then there is no point to check if its below zero because it's always positive.

Comment: How do you tell it to decelerate?

Comment: Anyways, in that case check whether the dot product of the acceleration and velocity is less, than 0

Comment: yes you're right it decelerates when dot is less than 0 and indeed your condition seems to work using the dot result instead of acceleration

Comment: In general 3D motion the speed will never "go through zero". Consider the earth going around the sun... after 1/2 year, the velocity will be in the opposite direction, but the speed was never zero. This is the usual case. Unless you have something artificial in your game/software to exactly align the velocity and acceleration, of the infinite directions each of these can take, they are almost never exactly aligned in real life. All this is to say, I wonder if you need a better definition of what you're really looking for, something like "change of direction", not "zero speed"?

Comment: Well an object can cross zero if its acceleration is the exact opposite direction of its velocity as you pointed out. Its not about direction, its only about speed (as magnitude). Bálint answer helps me to detect the change of sign of speed derivative, but it doesn't help my problem because because that sign can change whether or not I am near zero... its not sufficient to tell that I crossed zero. For that I need to predict the amount of delta speed for next frame: on my example 2 to 1, imagine it crosses zero, it means delta is 4 (2,1,0,1), I need that information. So that I could know 2-4<0

Comment: (delta is 3 actually in that example*). And I don't know how to predict that delta, I am gonna look into this.

Comment: Then, if the component of **v** parallel to **a** changes signs, that component has gone through zero, and the minimum difference of the speed from zero is the component of **v** perpendicular to **a** (which is constant throughout).  (Of course, if they are exactly parallel, then the speed actually goes through exactly zero.)

Comment: nice idea thanks, so I can get the speed change information tracking the parallel component, and minimum from perpendicular component. I think that'll do it.

Comment: I'm glad it will work. I'll try to write the up as an answer in a few days, but feel free to do it before then if you wish (and I'll upvote it). It seems good for this to have an accepted answer, but I don't have the time for it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tom10's idea, here is the solution I came up with for minimum detection when speed variation switches:

```
int speedCheck(bool variationSwitch, float& speed, float minThSpeed, float minSpeed, float maxSpeed) {
    // if change in speed variation ( decrease to minimum and increase again )
    if (variationSwitch) {
        // check if the theorical minimum speed that has been crossed is inferior to set up minimum speed
        if (minThSpeed <= minSpeed) {
            speed = minSpeed;
            return 3;
        }
    }
    else if (speed < minSpeed) {
        speed = minSpeed;
        return 2;
    }
    else if (speed > maxSpeed) {
        speed = maxSpeed;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With `variationSwitch` calculated by checking the signs of dot products of speed & acceleration before and after applying acceleration:

```
lastParallelComponent = glm::dot(acceleration, lastSpeed); 

speed += acceleration;

parallelComponent = glm::dot(acceleration, speed);

variationSwitch = lastParallelComponent * parallelComponent < 0.0f;
```

The theorical minimum speed, `minThSpeed` can be estimated with perpendicular component of speed over acceleration but I wasn't convinced about its accuracy so instead I calculated it using equations:

```
float get3DMinSpeed(Vector3f acceleration, Vector3f lastSpeed) {
    // t² * a + t*b + c = |v(t)|²

    float a = glm::dot(acceleration, acceleration);
    float b = 2 * glm::dot(acceleration, lastSpeed);
    float c = glm::dot(lastSpeed, lastSpeed);
    float t = -b / (2 * a);

    float min = (t*t)*a + t * b + c;
    float epsilon = 0.001f;

    if (min > 0.0f + epsilon)
        return sqrt(min);
    else
        return 0.0f;
}
```

So `minThSpeed`can be updated with that function each time a new acceleration is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dot product of the acceleration is less, than 0, if it is, check if the acceleration's magnitude is larger, than the magnitude of the velocity. If both of these are true, then it will change direction the next frame.